# handling two inputs under one onClick event

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am completely new to android development, my problem is that i had two editText boxes in my layout and self created number button 0-9,enterButton and Clr button. now my problem is to get two inputs from user via these number button in two diffrent editText boxes. Help me out!!!
Here is the code`@Override

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    // button clicked
    if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonEnter) {
        // enter button


        }

    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonClr) {
        // clear button


    } else {
        // number button 
        response.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        // here i want to take two inputs by clicking two buttons and display them
        int entered1 = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
        editTxt1.setText(String.valueOf(entered1));

        int entered2 = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
        editTxt2.setText(String.valueOf(entered2));
    }   
}`

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:tag="1"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />`
```

Comment: thanks! Daniel. pls Help me out  @DanielB

Comment: I had posted the Button initialization @DanielB

Answer (score 0):

Ok i get what you are trying to do, but why are you retrieving theTag, which appears to be a String from the view, then parse it to int, just to make it a string again?

besides that, id like to see the Button initialization, so i can understand what exactly the tag is.